# is_single() function dose not show thumbnail image

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am using `get_template_part('content');` in `single.php`. The `the_post_thumbnail('large-thumbnail');` function shows the thumbnail image perfectly before. But it does not show with `is_single()` function in `content.php`.

content.php code:

```
<?php
if(is_single()){
the_post_thumbnail('large-thumbnail');
the_content();
}else{
the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail');
echo get_the_excerpt();
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more&raquo;</a>
<?php } ?>
```

single.php:

```
<article>
        <div class="single_post_content">
            <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>

            <?php
            get_template_part('content');
            ?>
        </div>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to write wp loop in your single.php file. follow this code,

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part('content');    
endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

the_post_thumbnail() do not work out of wp loop, So call your get_template_part() function between the loop. May be now its will solve your problem.